# Подмена апи при e2e тестировании

Tags: angular, protractor

Есть задача покрыть проект Angular e2e тестами. Но столкнулся с рядом проблем в результате чего нужно подменять АПИ. Как я понял [из ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36354233/protractor-mocking-backend-with-angular2-on-api-request/36457515)
в Protractor нельзя замокать бэкенд.

Как это правильно сделать?